# Method works fine in iPython but runs endlessly on Gunicorn

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, wsgi, gunicorn, falconframework

I wrote an app in Falcon framework that I am running using the Gunicorn server. When the server starts, the app first learns random forest model:

```
forest = sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=150, n_jobs=-1)
forest.fit(x, t)
```

and then returns probabilities for requests posted to it. This works fine on my server when I run the code in iPython (training this model takes 15s, running on 12 cores).

When I was writing the app, i set `n_estimators=10` and everything was working. When I finished tweaking the app, I set `n_estimators` back to 150. However, when I ran Gunicorn then with `gunicorn -c ./app.conf app:app`, from htop I could see the the `forest.fit(x, t)` runs for few seconds on all cores, after which the usage of all cores drops to 0. After that, the method keeps running indefinitely until the Gunicorn worker timeouts after 10 minutes.

This is my first time using Gunicorn and Falcon, or any WSGI technologies for that matter, and I am clueless as to what might be causing the problem or how to troubleshoot it.

**Edit:**

The settings file for gunicorn:

```
# app.conf
# run with gunicorn -c ./app.conf app:app 
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/project/Module')

bind = "127.0.0.1:8123"
timeout = 60*20 # Timeout worker after more than 20 minutes`
```

The falcon code:

```
class Processor(object):
    """ Processor object handles the training of the models, 
    feature generation of requests and probability predictions. 
    """
    # data statistics used in feature calculations
    data_statistics = {}

    # Classification targets
    targets = ()

    # Select features for the models.
    cols1 = [ #... 
            ]

    cols2 = [ #...
            ]
    model_1 = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=150, n_jobs=-1)
    model_2 = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=150, n_jobs=-1)

    def __init__(self, features_dataset, tr_prepro):
        # Get the datasets
        da_1, da_2 = self.prepare_datasets(features_dataset)
        # Train models
# ----THIS IS WHERE THE PROGRAM HANGS -----------------------------------
        self.model_1.fit(da_1.x, utils.vectors_to_labels(da_1.t))
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.model_2.fit(da_2.x, utils.vectors_to_labels(da_2.t))
        # Generate data statistics for feature calculations
        self.calculate_data_statistics(tr_prepro)

    def prepare_datasets(self, features_dataset):
        sel_cols = [ #... 
                   ]

        # Build dataset
        d = features_dataset[sel_cols].dropna()
        da, scalers = ft.build_dataset(d, scaling='std', target_feature='outcome')

        # Binirize data
        da_bin = utils.binirize_dataset(da)

        # What are the classification targets
        self.targets = da_bin.t_labels

        # Prepare the datasets
        da_1 = da_bin.select_attributes(self.cols1)
        da_2 = da_bin.select_attributes(self.cols2)
        return da_1, da_2

    def calculate_data_statistics(self, tr_prepro):
        logger.info('Getting data and feature statistics...')
        #...
        logger.info('Done.')

    def import_data(self, data):
        # convert dictionary generated from json to Pandas DataFrame
        return tr

    def generate_features(self, tr):
        # Preprocessing, Feature calculations, imputation 
        return tr

    def predict_proba(self, data):
        # Convert Data
        tr = self.import_data(data)
        # Generate features
        tr = self.generate_features(tr)
        # Select model based on missing values - either no. 1 or no. 2
        tr_1 = #...
        tr_2 = #...
        # Get the probabilities from different models
        if tr_1.shape[0] > 0:
            tr_1.loc[:, 'prob'] = self.model_1.predict_proba(tr_1.loc[:, self.cols1])[:, self.targets.index('POSITIVE')]
        if tr_2.shape[0] > 0:
            tr_2.loc[:, 'prob'] = self.model_2.predict_proba(tr_2.loc[:, self.cols2])[:, self.targets.index('POSITIVE')]
        return pd.concat([tr_1, tr_2], axis=0)

    @staticmethod
    def export_single_result(tr):
        result = {'sample_id': tr.loc[0, 'sample_id'],
                  'batch_id': tr.loc[0, 'batch_id'],
                  'prob': tr.loc[0, 'prob']
                  }
        return result

class JSONTranslator(object):
    def process_request(self, req, resp):
        """Generic method for extracting json from requets

        Throws
        ------
        HTTP 400 (Bad Request)
        HTTP 753 ('Syntax Error')
        """
        if req.content_length in (None, 0):
            # Nothing to do
            return
        body = req.stream.read()
        if not body:
            raise falcon.HTTPBadRequest('Empty request body',
                                        'A valid JSON document is required.')
        try:
            req.context['data'] = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))
        except (ValueError, UnicodeDecodeError):
            raise falcon.HTTPError(falcon.HTTP_753,
                                   'Malformed JSON',
                                   'Could not decode the request body. The '
                                   'JSON was incorrect or not encoded as '
                                   'UTF-8.')

    def process_response(self, req, resp, resource):
        """Generic method for putting response to json
        Does not do anything if 'result_json' not in req.context.
        """
        if 'result_json' not in req.context:
            return
        resp.body = json.dumps(req.context['result_json'])

class ProbResource(object):

    def __init__(self, processor):
        self.schema_raw = open(config.__ROOT__ + "app_docs/broadcast_schema.json").read()
        self.schema = json.loads(self.schema_raw)
        self.processor = processor

    def validate_request(self, req):
        """ Validate the request json against the schema.
        Throws
        ------
        HTTP 753 ('Syntax Error')
        """       
        data = req.context['data']
        # validate the json
        try:
            v = jsonschema.Draft4Validator(self.schema)  # using jsonschema draft 4
            err_msg = str()
            for error in sorted(v.iter_errors(data), key=str):
                err_msg += str(error)

            if len(err_msg) > 0:
                raise falcon.HTTPError(falcon.HTTP_753,
                                       'JSON failed validation',
                                       err_msg)
        except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
            print("Failed to use schema:\n" + str(self.schema_raw))
            raise e

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        """Handles GET requests

        Throws
        ------
        HTTP 404 (Not Found)
        """
        self.validate_request(req)
        data = req.context['data']
        try:
            # get probability
            tr = self.processor.predict_proba(data)
            # convert pandas dataframe to dictionary
            result = self.processor.export_single_result(tr)
            # send the dictionary away
            req.context['result_json'] = result
        except Exception as ex:
            raise falcon.HTTPError(falcon.HTTP_404, 'Error', ex.message)
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200


# Get data
features_data = fastserialize.load(config.__ROOT__ + 'data/samples.s')
prepro_data = fastserialize.load(config.__ROOT__ + 'data/prepro/samples_preprocessed.s')

# Get the models - this is where the code hangs
sp = SampleProcessor(features_data, prepro_data)

app = falcon.API(middleware=[JSONTranslator()])

prob = ProbResource(sp)

app.add_route('/prob', prob)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information about your setting. What is your configuration, how are your Falcon resources set etc?

Comment: Ok, I added the code to the question, i tried to remove as much clutter as possible, but it is still quite a big chunk.

Comment: Without running the code, it seems to me that the problem arises because your processor overloads `gunicorn`; have you tried creating the `sp` instance inside the `ProbResource` instead rather than passing it to it?

Comment: I have not tried this before, does it make difference where I create the object?

Comment: Ok, I tried creating the `sp` instance in the `__init__` of the `ProbResource` and there is no difference in behaviour :-(

Comment: Yes, I realised since that it's not really a big difference here. As a rule, you should avoid keeping the state in the app or resource itself; creating the processor in the `on_get` might have better results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103609/discussion-between-bozenkhaa-and-berislav-lopac).